# How to create a cycling clock circuit from scratch?

Tags: circuit-design, clock

I'm thinking about doing a project where I have basic components (hex inverter chips, breadboards, jumper wires, transistors, capacitors, etc.) and I create a simple computer. I've been trying to design a circuit that will have a clock (I don't want to use 555 chips for this challenge) and it will cycle through the outputs one by one, restarting once it reaches the end (see the truth table below).
T----IN----OUT1----OUT2----OUT3----OUT4
1----DC----on--------off----------off---------off
2----DC----off-------on-----------off---------off
3----DC----off-------off-----------on--------off
4----DC----off-------off-----------off--------on
5----DC----on------off------------off--------off
T represents time (probably `1T=10ms`), the `DC` under `IN` means that it's just steady dc voltage, and I think the rest is pretty self-explanatory. I really don't know what something like this would look like, so anything would help. Thanks in advance!
EDIT:
Would the attached schematic work (not gates inserting energy to the circuit)?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdEaB1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Quick input means just a quick burst of power (possibly a capacitor discharge) that sets off the whole circuit

Comment: Nothing to do with you sat on a bicycle then?

Comment: useful search terms : Johnson counter, ring counter.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.

Comment: "a cycling clock" as in something used in a velodrome (possibly).

Comment: This would at minimum involve the functionality known as a "flip-flop" and likely additional combinatorial logic as well.  Realize you are a long way from building a computer; typically what is useful is to play with some 74xx series logic on a breadboard at a small scale, but before the complexity gets insane then switch to Verilog or VHDL and target simulation or an FPGA by the time you get into state machines and definitely before you get into anything resembling a traditional stored program computer.  The people building *those* on breadboards are, um, oddly motivated.

Comment: If you wired a not gate to itself (with some extra power added each cycle to prevent it dying out on itself) would that oscillate like a clock circuit?

Comment: Ring oscillators are a practical extension of that idea you can read about, but they won't *sequence*.  For that you need flip flops.

Comment: @ChrisStratton it wouldn't be a full-on computer, but more of a CPU with a custom assembly language, and ALU, and some memory. Maybe a small lcd screen for an output.

Comment: That's very much a "full on computer"!   Go have a look at something like the MIT open courseware 6.004 class to understand how you get from logic gates and flip flops to a processor capable of running even the most primitive sort of program.

Comment: Well I see no reason that I'm so far away from doing that. I've got everything else planned out, there's just this one thing that I need to work on.

Comment: You're on a great and absolutely worthwhile quest of learning, but your "there's just this one thing" is a demonstration of the basic fact that *you don't know what you don't know*.  Fortunately, what you *need* to know is basically a semester long class in any engineering program, and at least one (probably more) has its full contents available for free online: logic gates, flip flops, state machines, programmed machines.  You need to understand *each*, and *then* you can build a computer... but once you understand the complexity, you'll probably not chose to breadboard it.

Comment: I don't really prefer soldering, and it'll probably have a 3-bit CPU, as the assembly language won't have many commands.

Comment: Your attempt to utilize propagation delays is clever, but not really *useful* - you'll find it near impossible to do useful computation in such a way.  Rather, start by studying the idea of *sequential logic*.

Comment: Designing the instruction set for a 3-bit computer would be an interesting intellectual exercise; definitely the sort of thing where you want to prove it out in *simulation* before you build it.  I'd actually argue that you first write a C or python or whatever program as a high level simulation, then do a synthesizable implementation in Verilog or VHDL to simulate, and then either play with it in an FPGA, or consider what it would really cost in parts count to build in a breadboard (if, and only if, you are a masochist).

Comment: I'd just write the programs in the assembly language rather than C or python.

Comment: Really what I'm trying to do right now is create a circuit that will send the instructions from the memory to the CPU one by one.

Comment: If you do want to experiment with the oscillator circuit in your question then take the OUTs from the inverter outputs, not the inputs. Run a simulation on the circuit and monitor the voltages at inputs and outputs to see why.

Comment: You misunderstand: designing a *useful* 3-bit instruction set is tricky, so the point of a C or python stage is to *simulate* a machine which can process your proposed assembly language, and let you validate that you can write actually useful programs using it, by having the C or python program interpret them.  Once you prove the instruction set, you can move on to a functional Verilog or VHDL implementation, validate that in simulation, and *then* you can consider target hardware.

Comment: "Really what I'm trying to do right now is create a circuit that will send the instructions from the memory to the CPU one by one." that would typically the *program counter* portion of CPU functionality.  In a system usefully using available memory technologies, it would be a binary counter, not a sequence one...  And it would be loadable in addition to simply counting, so that you can implement a starting point, and branch instructions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're proposing is called a *ring oscillator*.  They do get used inside ICs for example, but it's bound to give you some headaches if you're attempting to make it from ordinary parts on a breadboard.

Instead, go digital. Use a normal oscillator (yes, even a 555) and make a count sequence with two flip-flops and some gates. The circuit below is a Johnson counter, sometimes called a 'walking ring' counter, decoded with 4 AND gates to produce a 4-bit pulse train:

[image]

Simulate it here: [Decoded walking-ring counter](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgzCAMB0l3BWEB2aBOALGNAObCEAmQgNgEYwMQFJrrIAoMgkHHcE2syKsTkMtSYtCGWn1qEEJDlyEB3cIVoYyMklVUzGijSC0g9EqA129%20bWScWWwyGTnH3rrJw5ViXotyEJhC4M46vv6BMn4BGJ7BjvqeEXG0jABKrom%20mp6CAWBwvtBIhAVQUAXC4oTsYGSR0uA1Ar4lCKYhOfzeVowAsvp11ZG2DZJlioRqVgnGwZVV-LnmSQy94zLGq-rIASMtvZSL4FGb2-ktiv7iaDnK%20hPBF0oVl9utzO2SE9OvfFZvXa8kKpXASA8A8FxqKrg-xQqj3SqPREPRjMCrsUiaOoYxonM4CH7YAKQ8DAma2YEPQkuBZWfb-RR-KRrBFMky9DBYvQYSzYnavIi-AWs%20HoraIwhi%20GSMWUm49PrhCbc9F3U7lJQqmQcxUybJ0PE04w04hw1rG0Qa3wWkW%20SDsRl2iFCx2Mury7Ug9jKz0lIotVGW4ke4l62h44k0kP8YJRtEgpbncEmsFUMhBM3gtPM%203pgD2AiQehU3ACSBg8EgaHs0ikvoL4AYQA)

The benefit of using this approach is that the pulses are exactly timed, and because the counter changes only 1 bit at a time, the pulses are free from glitches.

As far as simulating a 'computer', that's a larger problem. A very basic system has the following elements:

- clock generator
- program store
- program counter
- instruction decode
- data path / ALU
- registers

You can make these from chips, and there's online tutorials on how to do that for well-known devices like the 6502 or 8080.

If you're brave enough... https://hackaday.com/2018/12/15/this-6502-made-from-74-series-logic-can-run-at-20-mhz/

Really, though, much easier to simulate this stuff using a hardware description language like Verilog or VHDL. You can get free eval tools from FPGA vendors to do that.

If you're comfortable with C, Verilog should be an easy transition. VHDL is more powerful than Verilog in some ways, but it is much wordier. The split is something like C vs. C++: FPGA people tend to use VHDL because they value its abstraction and strong typing (like C++); chip people tend to use Verilog because they value its low-level explicitness and weak typing (like C).

Still others don't care, and use something like Matlab or some other high-level flow to generate HDL code.

There are also graphical sim tools like Logisim that kind of work, but I don't think they work that well for bigger projects. You soon reach a point where the design resembles spaghetti, constrained by how you can draw it.

I've introduced you to a simulator: Falstad. It's pretty great for quick sims.  Of all the sims I've tried it does the best job at *visualizing* the circuit - especially tricky ones like the ring oscillator you proposed. It has lots of examples (yes, even the 555 - it's there too).

On the other hand... <insert hate for CircuitLab here.>

Big picture: Doing digital? Learn Verilog, and prosper.